# W2K12 R2 - Windows update fails to install newest patches. DISM doesn't work either.(Error: 0x800f0906)

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2012, dism, citrix

as I mentioned in tittle I have problem with installing newest patches, it fails everytime.

`NFC /SCANNOW` doesn't finds any corrupted files.

CHKDSK is also fine.

DISM - online\image  0x800f0906\0x800f081f

DISM leaves some details in EventLog like "89 corrupted files cannot be repaired"

DISM commands I have used:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:WIM:F:\Sources\Install.wim:1 /LimitAccess
```

Important information:
VM starts from CITRIX image, it's responsibility is to prepare new image version.
Disk C:(System) is attached to the VM.

I have tried anything I have could find in the Internet but nothing helps. I don't wont to restore image to the earlier working version, I am open for any suggestions.

Comment: https://www.800error.com/error-code-0x800f0906-Windows-Update-nicht-Installation-Microsoft#!

Answer (score 0):

Use the original Windows 2012 for your system. Load it up and try doing a repair in place.

That is the best thing to do.

If that fails, you would need to back up data and reinstall Windows 2012.

As Server 2012 is now, or about to be, out of support, you may wish to consider a more modern server version.

Comment: As far as I know I am not able to do it. If I understand it would require to attach windows.iso to the VM and change boot order. I am almost sure that I cant do it as VM has CITRIX boot.iso attached and it should be at first place.

Comment: That is the only way I know how to repair the Server OS, and it you cannot do that, then backup and reinstall is in order.  As Server 2012 is now or about to be out of support, you may wish to consider a more modern server.

Comment: I have just rechecked and I am not able to change boot order and try to do "repair" option. That sucks that I am not person to decide what windows server version we use .